# Java @Singleton EJB executing method at most every 5 seconds

Tags: java, timer, concurrency, singleton, ejb

Hi I am implementing a web application with email sending functionality. In order for our email server not to be blacklisted we have to send at most one email per 5 seconds. So I was thinking to create an `@Singleton` EJB Email sender, in that way only one EJB instance will be responsible for sending all the emails in whole application. How should I implement the 5 seconds counter in order to send at most 1 email per 5 seconds? e.g the class will look like that

```
  @Singleton
  public class EmailSender {
       public void sendEmail(String msg){
                 ....
       }
  }
```

Comment: I think a separate thread that checks a message queue for a new message every 5 seconds could work. It can be a simple loop, pop from the queue if there is something, send the message, sleep for 5 seconds, repeat.

Comment: Maybe an @schedule method that triggers every five seconds and pops from the queue.

Comment: Hi guys thank you for replying. Can you provide an example for your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using @Schedule:

```
@Singleton
public class EmailSender {
     Queue<Email> queue;

     @Schedule(second = "*/5", minute = "*", hour = "*")
     public void sendEmail(String msg){
          if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
               //get queue element and send email
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, a ConcurrentLinkedQueue should do right? Actually i have added also a method public void addEmailToQueue(Email email) {
  queue.add(email);
 }